# Displaying different instances of UserControl through DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

```
<UserControl x:Name="AView" .... />
public class AViewModel { .. }

<UserControl x:Name="ParentView">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type vm:AViewModel}>
      <vw:AView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ContentControl Content="{Binding PropertyA}" />
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding PropertyB}" Grid.Column="1" />
</UserControl

public class ParentViewModel
{
    public AViewModel PropertyA {get;set;}
    public AViewModel PropertyB {get;set;}
}
```

PropertyA and PropertyB hold references to different instances of AViewModel.

Q: How can I display **different** instances of AView in ContentControls that are bound to PropertyA and PropertyB?

Comment: what?? that will create 2 instances of `AView` inside each `ContentControl`. I don't know what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: Yep, I had a bug in code, it creates two instances. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML you posted will create 2 instances of `AView` inside each `ContentControl`.